# Kendo UI Chart errorLowField and errorHighField doesn't work

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

in my Kendo UI Line Chart the errorLowField and errorHighField doesn't work. Have anybody an idea or a solution for my problem. I try it already 
many hours, but i can't find the problem.
Here ist a link to [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ra65ma/aQeVe).

```
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
               var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: [{"TAG":"06.11.15","C_BM":"G11-N","low":"14.09","high":"25.82","AVG":"19.5"},
                               {"TAG":"06.11.15","C_BM":"G12-N","low":"12.32","high":"52.96","AVG":"19.54"},
                               {"TAG":"09.11.15","C_BM":"G11-N","low":"20.69","high":"52.72","AVG":"29.95"},
                               {"TAG":"09.11.15","C_BM":"G12-N","low":"15.24","high":"69.99","AVG":"29.97"},
                               {"TAG":"08.11.15","C_BM":"G11-N","low":"21.96","high":"35.19","AVG":"31.11"},
                               {"TAG":"08.11.15","C_BM":"G12-N","low":"22.39","high":"68.9","AVG":"10.91"}],
                        group: {
                            field:"C_BM"
                        }
                    });

                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    dataSource: ds,
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "line"
                    },
                    series: [{ 
                        errorLowField: "low",
                        errorHighField: "high",
                        field: "AVG"
                    }],
                    categoryAxis: {
                        field: "TAG",
                        labels: { rotation: -90}
                    }
                });
   </script>
```

Comment: Make your values numbers instead of strings:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AvUJI

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It was misleading, because the field parameter are working.